# Extracting diagnostic logs from iPad 2 with macOS Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, logs, ipados

I have an iPad 2 from wich I want to extract the diagnostic logs.

The use case is a failed activation that blocks me from using the iPad or restoring it with my Laptop. I have a [separate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411514/ipad-2-activation-required-and-failed-out-of-nowhere-not-activation-lock) for that.

The iPad probably has iOS 9.3.6 installed but I can't say that for certain as I can't check.
The MacBook has macOS 10.15.7 (19H114) installed.

When connecting the iPad Finder just shows me the failed activation message after trying to activate it. I can't figure out how to get the logs as suggested by @bmike in the other question.